# SQL identifying changes in chronological order

Tags: sql, oracle

I could really use some help with SQL

I have a table with a row for every user for every day

```
UID DATE       ATTRIBUTE
123 2017-01-01 Awesome
123 2017-01-02 Awesome
123 2017-01-03 Awesome
123 2017-01-04 Not Awesome
123 2017-01-05 Awesome
123 2017-01-06 Awesome
123 2017-01-07 Awesome
166 2017-01-01 Kinda Awesome
166 2017-01-02 Awesome
166 2017-01-03 Awesome
166 2017-01-04 Really Awesome
166 2017-01-05 Awesome
166 2017-01-06 Awesome
166 2017-01-07 Awesome
```

I want to write a SQL query that will allow me to identify the date that the attribute changes for any user, the user's previous attribute, and the user's new attribute.

I don't really know where to even start.

Comment: Which database are  you using?

Comment: I am pulling data from an Oracle database

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function `lag` to check if the current row value matches the last row function:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        case 
            when attribute <> lag(attribute, 1, attribute) over (
                    partition by uid_ order by date_
                    )
                then 1
            else 0
            end as flag
    from your_table t
    ) t
where flag = 1;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/YJDAD86204)

Please try not to use reserved keywords such as UID, DATE as identifiers (I've added an underscore `_` to them in the solution).

Comment: Will do. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  *
from
(
  select
    u.uid,
    u.attribute,
    u.date,
    lag(u.attribute)
      over (partition by u.uid order by u.date) as prev_attribute,
    lag(u.date)
      over (partition by u.uid order by u.date) as prev_date
  from users u
) t
where t.attribute <> t.prev_attribute
```